# Updating the widget

Tags: android, widget

I want the widget in my app to be updated automatically without having the user to enter the app. So this is my code.

```
public class NewsAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

static ArrayList<News> newsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_grid_view);

    // Construct the RemoteViews object


    // Set the GridWidgetService intent to act as the adapter for the GridView
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GridWidgetService.class);
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_grid_view, intent);

    Intent templateIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
    templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, templateIntent, 0);

    views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_grid_view,
            templatePendingIntent);
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

public static void updateRecipeWidgets(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, NewsAppWidgetProvider.class));

    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE2")) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = prefs.getString("news", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>(){}.getType();
        newsArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_grid_view);
        //Now update all widgets
        NewsAppWidgetProvider.updateRecipeWidgets(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
        super.onReceive(context,intent);
    }
}
}
```

So how can I do that?

**UPDATE**

I did some changes first I read the json file with Gson inside the **updateAppWidget** which called in **onUpdate**. Next, I use the standard action **android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE** inside the **onReceive** So.

```
public class NewsAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

static ArrayList<News> newsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static String json;
private static Type type;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;
private static Gson gson;

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_grid_view);

    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, NewsAppWidgetProvider.class));

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    gson = new Gson();
    json = prefs.getString("news", "");
    type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>(){}.getType();
    newsArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_grid_view);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    // Set the GridWidgetService intent to act as the adapter for the GridView
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GridWidgetService.class);
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_grid_view, intent);

    Intent templateIntent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
    templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, templateIntent, 0);

    views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_grid_view,
            templatePendingIntent);
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

public static void updateRecipeWidgets(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, NewsAppWidgetProvider.class));

    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE")) {
        NewsAppWidgetProvider.updateRecipeWidgets(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
        super.onReceive(context,intent);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Are you saying yours isn't automatically updating as it normally should? If that's what you mean, it's because you have the `super.onReceive(context, intent)` call in the wrong spot. That should be in an `else` on that `if`.

Comment: Hello Mike M. It updates only after I enter my app. So you mentioned that the super.onReceive(context,intent) is in a wrong spot?

Comment: Yeah, but that might not be the only issue, depending on what you mean. `onReceive()` in `AppWidgetProvider` delegates the regular Widget broadcasts to their respective methods. You're basically blocking all those broadcasts, so `onUpdate()` never gets called. However, if want all that `SharedPreferences`/JSON stuff to happen in regular updates, then that needs to be called in `onUpdate()`, too. Also, if you're trying to do an update whenever your app opens, in addition to the regular updates, then you should just send a normal `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast, rather than defining your own action

Comment: Hello Mike M. Please see my update and comment it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the whole picture is, here. Do you really need to override `onReceive()` at all? It doesn't seem like it. As I mentioned, if you're just trying to trigger an update whenever the user opens the app, then you can get rid of the `onReceive()` override altogether, and send a regular `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast, [like this example, in an `Activity` or `Service`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UNaG4PYC3t2ddGyrXajLm4X65mT-r06j/view?usp=drivesdk). Sorry, my previous comment wasn't really clear about that, now that I read it again.

Comment: Hey Mike M. It's ok. In my app I have 8 tabs. And each tab represents news fetched from different media. ie. Tab1 = CNN, Tab2 = BBC, Tab3 =  Daily Mail and so on. When I go to the 4th tab and exit the app, the widget will display that specific news in a list. The same happens if I click in any other tab. So that's good. All I was asking is how to update let's say bbc news in widget without having to enter the app.

Comment: You can run my project if you want. All you need is clone it https://github.com/theo82/Capstone-Udacity. You register in firebase (which works perfectly) see the news and try the widget. You will understand it better that way.

Comment: Well, Widgets automatically update their UI every 30 minutes or so, by default. That is, `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` is broadcast, and `onUpdate()` is called, if nothing stops it. That's what I thought you were referring to. If you're saying that you want to automatically pull fresh news from a site, and update the Widget with that, then you're going to need to somehow schedule something to do your network fetch, then trigger the Widget update; for example, with `AlarmManager`, or possibly `JobScheduler` on newer versions.

Comment: Oh, if you're using Firebase already, there's also [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling#fjd), but I'm not at all familiar with it.